# Organization level webhooks

Tags: github

Is there a way to receive callback after every action taken on any repo, by any user in my Github organization? I know that there are repo-level webhooks, but if you have many repos in your organization it may be problematic to always keep them up to date in all repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are organization level hooks which you can configure provided you are an admin of the org. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/hooks/#create-a-hook).

To create a hook for an event on the organization, you would need to make a post request with the payload specified in [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/hooks/#create-a-hook) to:

```
POST /orgs/:org/hooks
```

An `events` array is passed in the payload that specifies which events the hook is configured for. A `config` object is passed in the payload, using which you can specify the URL to which the payloads will be delivered.